# MVC List<> error in model in reference to another model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is an error in `List<Story>`:

> the type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
>   [project]

```
using System;
using project.Models;

namespace project.Models
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Story> Stories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Collections.Generic` to the top of your class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

---

From your comment:

> have another question: is it necessary to write `namespace project.Models?` and the reason

Namespaces are not mandatory but they help organise your code.

You don't need this line `using project.Models;` at the top of your class `Genre`.  `Genre` is already in the namespace `project.Models` since you define that here:

```
// define the namespace for Genre
namespace project.Models
{
```

Since `Genre` is in the namespace `project.Models` you can reference any other class in `Models` without adding an explicit `using`.

However, when you reference `Genre` from a class which is in a different namespace (not in `project.Models`) you *will* need to add `using project.Models` to the top of that class.  Otherwise, you could use the full reference `Models.Genre`.

[This link](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/namespaces) has a good explanation of declaring, accessing and using namespaces.

Comment: have another question: is it necessary to write ```namespace project.Models```? and the reason

Comment: Namespaces are not mandatory but they help organise your code (especially for larger projects).  When you use your class `Genre` in another class you will need to add `using project.Models` at the top of the class, or use `Models.Genre` when referencing `Genre` @DanabekDuisekov

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov I've updated my answer with info on namespaces

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a using statement `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic`
this is all you need